# Fix seed globaly in c++11 <random>

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm trying to use the new `c++` `<random>` headers with a globally fixed seed. Here is my first toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int morerandom(const int seednum,const int nmax){
     std::mt19937 mt;
     mt.seed(seednum);
     std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint(0,nmax);
     return(uint(mt));
}
int main(){
    const int seed=3;
    for (unsigned k=0; k<5; k++){
        std::cout << morerandom(seed,10) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is: how can I fix the seed in the `main()` and get reproducible output out of 
`morerandom()`?

In other words, I need  to call `morerandom()` a lot (`k` will be large) but these random numbers should always be drawn using the same `seed`. I'm wondering whether it is possible/more efficient to define the whole block:

```
std::mt19937 mt;
mt.seed(seednum);
```

inside the main and just pass `mt` to `morerandom()`. I tried that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int morerandom(const int nmax)
{

     std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint(0,nmax);
     return(uint(mt));
}


int main()
{
    const int seed=3;
    std::mt19937 mt;
    mt.seed(seed);
    for (unsigned k=0; k<5; k++)
    {

        std::cout << morerandom(10) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler complains:

```
error: ‘mt’ was not declared in this scope return(uint(mt));
```

Comment: The compiler complains rightly, as the name `mt` is not known inside of `morerandom`. Please make clear what exactly it is that you want to do. I don't really understand what you are up to.

Comment: @filmore: I didn't know how to pass a mt to a function (was searching everywhere & couldn't find it!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Solution 1***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int morerandom(const int nmax, std::mt19937& mt)
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{    
     std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint(0,nmax);
     return(uint(mt));
}    

int main()
{
    const int seed=3;
    std::mt19937 mt;
    mt.seed(seed);
    for (unsigned k=0; k<5; k++)
    {    
        std::cout << morerandom(10, mt) << std::endl;
        //                          ^^
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***Solution 2***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

std::mt19937 mt;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

int morerandom(const int nmax)
{    
     std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uint(0,nmax);
     return(uint(mt));
}    

int main()
{
    const int seed=3;
    mt.seed(seed);
    for (unsigned k=0; k<5; k++)
    {    
        std::cout << morerandom(10) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```